# Design pattern: How to create synchronized method or block in Singleton pattern in Java?

Tags: java, singleton, synchronized, synchronized-block

I am implementing a backend service using Java. I chose to apply the `Singleton` pattern because there should be only one service running. However, this service is also a Socket.IO client thus there must be some kind of event being triggered when server pushed. But the event should be `synchronized` in queue.

I think my implementation is not correct. Tt seems that  `synchronized(this)` block is NOT protecting the `Backend` object but rather the `Emitter.Listener` object.

```
private static synchronized BackendServer getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new BackendServer();
        try {
            socket = IO.socket(host_name+":"+port_frontend);
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                }
            }).on("event1", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    try {
                        synchronized(this) { <--Which object is synchronized?
                            String timestamp = getCurrentTime();
                            String logging = "["+timestamp+"] ";
```

Comment: Shouldn't the socket be created by an instance method of `BackendServer`? If it is the server, then style-wise you shouldn't create the socket separately from it.

Answer (score 3):

In the line you quoted, `this` indeed refers to the `Emitter.Listener` instance. So you are creating a synchronized block which uses the new `Emitter.Listener` instance as monitor. This is probably not what you want. If you want to synchronize on another object, you can put that in your synchronized block.

As a side remark, note that synchronized blocks do not *protect objects*. They make sure that the synchronized block (or any other synchronzied block with the same monitor) is not concurrently visisted by a different *thread*. If the same object has other non-synchornized code, that can be concurrently executed.

Comment: @RealSkeptic. Right. I missed that, thanks. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I do want to synchronize on BackendServer object. Can you please show me some code on how to achieve this inside the Emitter.Listener function?